# Troubles with errno.h

Tags: linux, redhat, errno

I'm working with Rad Hat 8.0, trying to make changes to the kernel, and I'm at the compilation stage. 
I have a header in include/linux where I define wrapper functions, and they use errno. I included errno.h using 
`#include <errno.h>`. 
When I try to compile, it tells me "errno.h no such file or directory". When I try 
`#include <linux/errno.h>`
it finds it but complains that I did not declare errno the variable before use. 
I looked at errno.h and it really doesn't have it declared, which is confusing because I was under the impression that this is where it is defined.

Am I looking in the wrong places? How do I make use of errno?

Answer (score 2):

For kernel code, `#include <linux/errno.h>`.

The extern declaration for `errno` is in `#include <linux/unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/building-module-errno-undeclared-910148/), `errno` variable is set automaticly when you return a negative value.

**Example**:

```
asmlinkage long sys_foo() {
    ...
    if(error)
        return -(errorcode);
    ...
}
```

In this case the returning result in userspace will be `-1` and `errno` variable will have value of `errorcode`.

Answer (score 0):

errno is defined as an extern in

```
/usr/src/lib/linux/errno.c
```

you have to compile this file with yours